# understanding sockets - c

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to understand more sockets. So I found in the header file `socket.h`, in the sys library, some functions declarations as `bind(), connect()`, but I didn't find their definitions ? Where can I find it ?

Tell me if this question, is not relevant, I will move it elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find their definitions in the headers, you need to dig in your libc. But you won't find anything truly useful there either, since those are system calls, so really you need to dig in your kernel.

Comment: Ok thank you ! Do you have an idea why I have been downvoted ?

Comment: @user1611830 Not sure. I think people vote pretty erratically sometimes. Perhaps they thought finding those definitions is really easy. I think it's pretty hard if you don't know exactly where to look.

Comment: @user1611830 0 downvotes and upvoted every answer. My kind of user :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're really suggested to read [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to network programming to make sense of these functions. Manpages (-S2) will help too.

The source code of the function (if that's what you hope to find) won't help a lot. They call system calls to do their job, as they're mostly OS-abstraction layer. What you need is their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you see http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm for more about sockets.